# Would like to implement 'screenshot' function and 'share' option in my Android app, but throwing error

Tags: java, android, share

I am building an android app and would like to implement 'screenshot' function and 'share'option in my Android app during on click on the share button.

But while running it is throwing following error and nothing happens on button click. Please help !

**Error Trying to load Staging Credentials: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Following is the code:

```
public class ShareActivity extends MainActivity{

Button share;
File imagePath;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    share  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share1);
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
            saveBitmap(bitmap);
            shareIt();
        }
    });
}

//Screenshot method to take the screenshot in app

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

    View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        //View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        //rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        //return rootView.getDrawingCache();
        //View screenView = view.getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

//ShareIt method to invoke the share the screen shot captured

private void shareIt() {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();   
     sharingIntent = intent.setType("image/*");
      //sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
     String shareBody = "In Tweecher, My highest score with screen shot";
     sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Tweecher score");
     sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
     sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
}
```

Stack Trace log:

```
09-14 21:25:21.470 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-14 21:25:21.881 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: Telemetry initialize() called...
09-14 21:25:21.883 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: Right before Telemetry set enabled in initialized()
09-14 21:25:21.888 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: setTelemetryEnabled(); this.telemetryEnabled = false; telemetryEnabled = true
09-14 21:25:21.888 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/MapboxEventManager: Starting Telemetry Up!
09-14 21:25:21.921 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: Permissions are good, see if GPS is enabled and if not then setup Ambient.
09-14 21:25:21.923 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp E/MapboxEventManager: Error Trying to load Staging Credentials: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
09-14 21:25:21.996 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-14 21:25:22.263 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/art: Thread[1,tid=2844,Native,Thread*=0xb40f4500,peer=0x73828258,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp-2/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so"
09-14 21:25:22.263 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/art: Thread[1,tid=2844,Native,Thread*=0xb40f4500,peer=0x73828258,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp-2/lib/x86/libmapbox-gl.so"
09-14 21:25:22.294 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp E/OfflineManager: Failed to read the storage key: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
09-14 21:25:22.359 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView: MapView start Telemetry...
09-14 21:25:22.360 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: Telemetry initialize() called...
09-14 21:25:22.360 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: Mapbox Telemetry has already been initialized.

                                                                              [ 09-14 21:25:22.361  2844: 2844 D/         ]
                                                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaabfdc0, tid 2844
09-14 21:25:22.387 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: EGL Vendor: Android
09-14 21:25:22.387 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: EGL Version: 1.4 Android META-EGL
09-14 21:25:22.387 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: EGL Client APIs: OpenGL_ES
09-14 21:25:22.387 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: EGL Client Extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_swap_buffers_with_damage EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 
09-14 21:25:22.387 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[Android]: In emulator! Enabling hacks :-(
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: Found 2 configs
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: Config 0:
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Caveat: 12344
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Conformant: 5
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Color: 32
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Red: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Green: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Blue: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Alpha: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Alpha mask: 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Depth: 24
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Stencil: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Sample buffers: 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Samples: 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: Config 1:
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Caveat: 12344
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Conformant: 5
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Color: 32
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Red: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Green: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Blue: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Alpha: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Alpha mask: 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Depth: 24
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Stencil: 8
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Sample buffers: 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: ...Samples: 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: Chosen config is 0
09-14 21:25:22.388 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: Chosen window format is 1
09-14 21:25:22.401 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapboxEventManager: flushEventsQueueImmediately() called...
09-14 21:25:22.403 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/MapboxEventManager: turnstile event pushed.
09-14 21:25:22.419 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/Network: Network
09-14 21:25:22.422 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/GPS Enabled: GPS Enabled
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:637)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:387)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myfirstglapp.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:133)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myfirstglapp.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:62)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myfirstglapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
09-14 21:25:22.434 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-14 21:25:22.435 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-14 21:25:22.435 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-14 21:25:22.435 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-14 21:25:22.435 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-14 21:25:22.435 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-14 21:25:22.446 2844-2872/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/GzipRequestInterceptor: Compressing
09-14 21:25:22.450 2844-2877/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-14 21:25:22.456 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/TelemetryService: onCreate() called
09-14 21:25:22.456 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/TelemetryService: onStartCommand() called
09-14 21:25:22.582 2844-2877/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                                          [ 09-14 21:25:22.583  2844: 2877 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa142310, tid 2877
09-14 21:25:22.699 2844-2877/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-14 21:25:22.699 2844-2877/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa0453360, error=EGL_SUCCESS

                                                                          [ 09-14 21:25:22.705  2878: 2903 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae4d28d0, tid 2903
09-14 21:25:22.829 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: GL Vendor: Google (Intel)
09-14 21:25:22.829 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: GL Renderer: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) HD Graphics 2000)
09-14 21:25:22.830 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: GL Version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.4229)
09-14 21:25:22.830 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: GL Extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
09-14 21:25:22.894 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/MapAsync:  is called
09-14 21:25:23.208 2844-2854/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7816(378KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 9.556ms total 19.844ms
09-14 21:25:23.290 2844-2854/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 81.700ms
09-14 21:25:23.315 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp W/mbgl: {ny.myfirstglapp}[OpenGL]: Not using Vertex Array Objects
09-14 21:25:23.609 2844-2844/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-14 21:25:23.809 2844-2923/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request with response code = 304: Not Modified
09-14 21:25:23.811 2844-2872/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/MapboxEventManager: response code = 204 for events 2
09-14 21:25:24.072 2844-2935/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp V/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request was successful (code = 200).
09-14 21:25:24.200 2844-2934/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp V/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request was successful (code = 200).
09-14 21:25:24.237 2844-2923/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp V/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request was successful (code = 200).
09-14 21:25:24.447 2844-2911/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request with response code = 304: Not Modified
09-14 21:25:24.502 2844-2935/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp V/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request was successful (code = 200).
09-14 21:25:24.525 2844-2892/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request with response code = 304: Not Modified
09-14 21:25:24.541 2844-2913/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request with response code = 304: Not Modified
09-14 21:25:31.922 2844-3063/com.mycompany.myfirstglapp D/MapboxEventManager: No events in the queue to send so returning.
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace,

Comment: Will post the full stacktrace shortly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Posted full stack trace

Comment: Please add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line in the stack trace. This will format it for easier reading.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I have necessary spaces in the stack trace

Comment: If `Trying to load Staging Credentials` is the error you are concerned about, you need to find and post the stacktrace for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The exception you have asked about refers to getString() but I don't see that in the code you have posted. Are you sure this is all the code you have in your application?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: That is the error that I am concerned about.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help. You need to post the stacktrace for the error you are asking about and the code that causes the error. You should also edit this question to remove any information which is irrelevant to the error you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Will edit and remove the irrelevant info  and will update with correct error info soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only stacktrace you have posted from your log cat is for the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

When you look down several lines, you will see

```
at com.mycompany.myfirstglapp.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:133)
```

This means that the error occurs because of something on line 133 in GPSTracker.java. This is in the `getLocation()` method of your `GPSTracker` class. You need to look at this line of code and use a debugger to determine which variable in that line of code is `null`. Since the stacktrace shows other methods from the call stack, most likely the problem is with one of the parameters that you are passing to the `getLocation()` method.

Comment: But the getLocation()  method under GPSTracker is working for me. I could see another error in 7 th line in stack trace, com.mycompany.myfirstglapp E/MapboxEventManager: Error Trying to load Staging Credentials: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @soccerway Then you need to get the stacktrace for that error to determine where the problem occurs.